# LPAD and RPAD on a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

I'm trying to pad to the left and right of a case statement with 3 asterisks.  It runs but the values don't show up for the Null values.  Any ideas?

```
SELECT p.patientfirstname || ' ' || p.patientlastname AS "Patient"  
,CASE WHEN i.insuranceid IS NULL THEN RPAD(LPAD('No insurance', 3, '*'), 3, '*')
 ELSE i.insurancename 
 END "Insurance Name"
FROM patient p 
FULL OUTER JOIN insurance i ON (p.insuranceid = i.insuranceid);
```

Comment: change `RPAD(LPAD('No insurance', 3, '*'), 3, '*')` to `RPAD(LPAD('No insurance', 15, '*'), 18, '*')` if you want to show up `***No insurance***`

Comment: Why not `COALESCE(i.insurancename, '***No insurance***')`? Also, the pad functions don't work the way you are using them. You are saying you want a string of size 3 returned. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm

Comment: If you want `***No insurance***` to show up, stop the padding and just type `'***No insurance***'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, if you want a constant string, just use one and do away with the padding:

```
 SELECT p.patientfirstname || ' ' || p.patientlastname AS "Patient"  
,CASE WHEN i.insuranceid IS NULL THEN '***No insurance***'
 ELSE i.insurancename 
 END "Insurance Name"
FROM patient p 
FULL OUTER JOIN insurance i ON (p.insuranceid = i.insuranceid);
```

Padding is used to ensure a fixed-size string when working with transforming strings that are of variable shorter sizes. See example:

```
select lpad('Hola',7, '*'),  lpad('Namaste',7, '*'), lpad('Hello',7, '*') from dual;
```

> ***Hola |Namaste |**Hello

```
select length(lpad('Hola',7, '*')),  length(lpad('Namaste',7, '*')), length(lpad('Hello',7, '*')) from dual;
```

> 7 |7  |7